# Voltage of IN pin of voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, ohms-law, non-linear

A voltage regulator has a constant output voltage regardless of the load so it can been seen as a voltage dependent resistance but I am wondering what will happen in this case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3od7y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since there is a 100 ohm resistor before the IN pin and assuming some current is flowing inside the voltage regulator there is a voltage drop across R1, how can we calculate the voltage at the IN pin?

Comment: By using Ohm's law? But that would be very short answer, what kind of aspect of this circuit are you thinking? Also, the circuit without capacitor on VIN pin could be unstable, so it would be better to move the capacitor on the other side of the 100R resistor.

Comment: It will share dissipation with the resistor but at the end you'll have more dropout

Answer (score 1):

If the regulator is operating properly (Vin - Vout) is "high enough" and the output current or power dissipation is not so high that it is limiting - then output voltage is 5V.

The input current is Iin = Iq + Iout where Iq (quiescent current) is around 5mA for the 7805. Therefore the resistor will drop 100\$\Omega\cdot\$Iin. You can go back and check that the input voltage has not dropped too far for the regulator to work properly.

Many regulators have an Iq that is fairly constant so this is a good approximation. A few have a nasty characteristic in that the internally used current (like Iq but not very quiescent) increases drastically near the dropout voltage to a fair fraction of the output current (because the on-chip lateral PNP has pretty miserable gain), which could cause this circuit to have a (typically very undesirable) bistable nature.

Also, as @Justme says in a comment, putting the input capacitor on that side of the 100 ohm resistor could cause stability issues depending on the load characteristics. It's very difficult to get that particular part to oscillate, but connecting the input cap that would be something to point it in that direction. IIRC it was the only way I could coax it close to instability.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ohm's law.

$$ V_{IN} = V_S - I_{R1}R_1 $$

It's just the supply voltage less the voltage drop due to the load current through R1.

If you want to be very accurate then add in the quiescent current for the regulator itself - usually a few mA and this information is available from the datasheet.

Comment: How can we calculate the IR1?

Comment: It's the current provided by the regulator to the load (+ the quiescent current drawn by the regulator).

Comment: Ah ok.Thanks a lot!

Comment: So current through the IN pin doesnt depend on R1?It doesnt seem right.

Comment: @CartoonRyan not until the input voltage drops too low causing the regulator to "drop out" and no longer supply the expected voltage on its output.

Comment: The 7805 needs at least 7 V on the input if it is to maintain 5 V on the output. A 100 Ω resistor will cause a 100 mV drop per mA flowing through it. The output voltage will remain constant 5 V until the current increases to the point that R1 causes \$ V_{IN}\$ to drop below 7 V. After that the output voltage will droop.